# CDI Beans module deployment failed- LifecycleException on deploying webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, apache-tomee

I'm trying to run a web-app on tomee1.7.1 in eclipse Luna. On adding java source source files, the server fails to start giving the below stacktrace. I'm stuck here for a few days now.

I'm running java 1.8.40. The problem is that I can't relate this stack trace to any of my code.

```
  INFO: OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
    Jul 13, 2015 4:46:43 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
    INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
    Jul 13, 2015 4:46:43 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
    INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
    Jul 13, 2015 4:46:46 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
    SEVERE: CDI Beans module deployment failed
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.webbeans.util.ClassUtil.getNonPrivateMethods(ClassUtil.java:292)
        at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorResolutionService.getInterceptableBusinessMethods(InterceptorResolutionService.java:560)
        at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorResolutionService.calculateInterceptorInfo(InterceptorResolutionService.java:91)
        at org.apache.webbeans.portable.AbstractProducer.defineInterceptorStack(AbstractProducer.java:82)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validate(BeansDeployer.java:474)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validateInjectionPoints(BeansDeployer.java:422)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:202)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:194)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:160)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:797)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:623)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Jul 13, 2015 4:46:46 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
    INFO: Undeploying app: D:\Softwares\eclipse\ecclipse_WS\13716x\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\enovia
    Jul 13, 2015 4:46:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase removeChild
    SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/enovia]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:409)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1524)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1505)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:747)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:1668)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:892)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:623)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Jul 13, 2015 4:46:47 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
    SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/enovia]
    org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: D:\Softwares\eclipse\ecclipse_WS\13716x\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\enovia: couldn't start owb context
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:896)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:623)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: couldn't start owb context
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:162)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:797)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:197)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:160)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.webbeans.util.ClassUtil.getNonPrivateMethods(ClassUtil.java:292)
        at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorResolutionService.getInterceptableBusinessMethods(InterceptorResolutionService.java:560)
        at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorResolutionService.calculateInterceptorInfo(InterceptorResolutionService.java:91)
        at org.apache.webbeans.portable.AbstractProducer.defineInterceptorStack(AbstractProducer.java:82)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validate(BeansDeployer.java:474)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validateInjectionPoints(BeansDeployer.java:422)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:202)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:194)
        ... 17 more

    Jul 13, 2015 4:46:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/enovia]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/enovia]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: D:\Softwares\eclipse\ecclipse_WS\13716x\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\enovia: couldn't start owb context
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1257)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: D:\Softwares\eclipse\ecclipse_WS\13716x\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\enovia: couldn't start owb context
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:896)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:623)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1248)
        ... 12 more
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: couldn't start owb context
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:162)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:797)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:197)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:160)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.webbeans.util.ClassUtil.getNonPrivateMethods(ClassUtil.java:292)
        at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorResolutionService.getInterceptableBusinessMethods(InterceptorResolutionService.java:560)
        at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorResolutionService.calculateInterceptorInfo(InterceptorResolutionService.java:91)
        at org.apache.webbeans.portable.AbstractProducer.defineInterceptorStack(AbstractProducer.java:82)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validate(BeansDeployer.java:474)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validateInjectionPoints(BeansDeployer.java:422)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:202)
        at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:194)
        ... 17 more

    Jul 13, 2015 4:46:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

    Jul 13, 2015 4:46:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[2022]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more
```

.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like WebBeans can't handle Java classes without any defined package. Are you declaring a package for all your files?